# How can I call a redux-saga on an interval?

Tags: redux-saga

I need to fetch data on an interval. I currently use a react component to house my logic and just render null, but I added redux-saga to my app and I would rather move the flow to a saga. I haven't been able to figure out how to have a generator callback or call a generator from a callback.

Here is what I have built so far:

```
// @flow
import { takeLatest, all, put, select } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

let timers: Array<IntervalID> = [];

const getUpdateInterval = (state) => state.settings.updateInterval;

const createTimer = (callback: Generator<any, any, any>, interval: number = 120) => {
  return setInterval(() => {
    callback.next();
  }, interval * 1000);
}

export default function * data (): Generator<any, any, any> {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(types.AUTHENTICATE_SUCCEEDED, fetchData),
    takeLatest(types.AUTHENTICATE_SUCCEEDED, setupTimers),
    takeLatest(types.AUTHENTICATE_FAILED, clearTimers),
    takeLatest(types.LOGGED_OUT, clearTimers)
  ]);
}

function * fetchData () {
  yield put({type: types.FETCH_DATA});
}

function * setupTimers () {
  const updateInterval = yield select(getUpdateInterval);

  clearTimers();

  const newTimer = createTimer(function * () {
    yield fetchData();
  }, updateInterval);

  timers.push(newTimer);
}

function clearTimers () {
  timers.forEach(clearInterval);
  timers = [];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't been able to figure out how to have a generator callback or call a generator from a callback.

I suspect that your code is going to end up pretty thorny if you're combining redux-saga & callbacks. For this case, how about using `delay`?

```js
function* callInAnInterval (fn) {
  while (yield select(shouldFetch)) {
    yield call(fn)
    const updateInterval = yield select(getUpdateInterval);
    yield delay(updateInterval)
  }

}
```

Comment: I think `yield fork(fn)` is more similar to `setInterval`

Comment: I don't see a way to use `delay` to replace my old implementation (clearable, reinitiate with a new interval, `delay` is blocking). I decided this was not a good bit of code to refactor after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
export function* watchGetSomething() {
    yield takeEvery(GET_SOMETHING, getSomethingFlow);
}

function* getSomethingFlow({offset, limit}: IGetSomething) {
    try {
        do {
            const result = yield call(Api.getSomething, offset, limit);
            yield put(setSomething(result.data.payload));
            yield delay(60 * 1000);
        } while (true);
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(putSnackbarMessage(SOMETHING_GET_ERROR));
    }
}
```